# How can I save the information from yfinance responses

Tags: python, python-3.x, yfinance

```
import yfinance as yf
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pandas import DataFrame


startDate = datetime.now ()- timedelta(100)
endday = datetime.now()-timedelta(-1)


stockNo = xxx      # xxx1, xxx2, ...stock code
start = startDate, end = endday
stock = yf.Ticker(stockNo)

stock_df = pd.DataFrame(stock.history(start = startDate, end = endday ))
```

yfinance responses as follow, how can i save this information as list or dataframe

- xxx1: No data found, symbol may be delisted
- xxx2: No data found, symbol may be delisted

Answer (score 0):

This is a really late answer, but considering there are none yet:

```
import yfinance as yf 
import pandas as pd

ticker = "ENTER_YOUR_TICKER_HERE"

yahootickerdata = yf.Ticker(f"{ticker}")

# this is already a dataframe so no  need to read it in as one
# but this depends on what you're requesting from yfinance
earnings = yahootickerdata.earnings

# save to CSV
earnings.to_csv(f"data/{ticker}-yahoo-earnings.csv")

# and next time you can just load the CSV
df = pd.read_csv(f"data/{ticker}-yahoo-earnings.csv")
```